# Undefined method error when I add method to model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the error

undefined method events_and_repeats' for `#<Class:0x429c840>`

app/controllers/events_controller.rb:11:in `index'

my app/models/event.rb is

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates :title, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :minimum => 5 }
  validates :shedule, :presence => true

  require 'ice_cube'
  include IceCube

  def events_and_repeats(date)
    @events = self.where(shedule:date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month)

    return @events
  end

end
```

app/controllers/events_controller.rb

```
def index
    @date = params[:month] ? Date.parse(params[:month]) : Date.today
    @repeats = Event.events_and_repeats(@date)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @events }
    end
  end
```

What is wrong?

Comment: just need a 'self' - you made an instance method, but called a class method

Comment: Self where? Please give me an example. And what is difference? Thanks

Comment: Check Zippie's response, I think it's all covered there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like Swards said, you called a instance method on a class. Rename it:

```
def self.events_and_repeats(date)
```

I am only writting this in an answer because it's too long for a comment,
checkout the ice-cube github page, it strictly says:

```
Include IceCube inside and at the top of your ActiveRecord model file to use the IceCube classes easily.
```

Also i think it you don't need the `require` in your model.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! May be you may help me resolve one more issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15790909/gem-ice-cube-for-reccurence-events

Answer (score 4):

You can do it both ways:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  class << self
    def events_and_repeats(date)
      where(shedule:date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month)
    end
  end

end
```

or

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...

  def self.events_and_repeats(date)
    where(shedule:date.beginning_of_month..date.end_of_month)
  end    
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I will know it )

Comment: You're welcome! A couple of thing, you don't need the `@events`at all, ruby methods will return the last evaluated statement. Moreover, `self.where()` is also not necessary because you're calling `where()` already inside `self`. Glad I was able to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just for more clarity:

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
    puts 'class method'
  end

  def baz
    puts 'instance method'
  end
end

Foo.bar # => "class method"
Foo.baz # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘baz’ for Foo:Class

Foo.new.baz # => instance method
Foo.new.bar # => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘bar’ for #<Foo:0x1e820>
```

[Class method and Instance method](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/)