# Rails 4 - Loading ActiveRecord Associations and Output as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, include, recurring-events

I have the following schema for displaying events with FullCalendar:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_occurrences, dependent: :destroy

  def as_json(options = {})
   {
  :id => self.id,
  :title => self.name,
  :start => start_time.rfc822,
  :end => end_time.rfc822,
  }
  end
end

class EventOccurence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
end
```

The makeup of an **Event** object (I've removed some fields for brevity):

```
   => Event(id: integer, name: string, start_time: datetime, end_time: datetime)
```

The makeup of an **EventOccurence** object:

```
   => EventOccurrence(id: integer, event_id: integer, date: datetime)
```

The **JSON output** would look like this:

```
 {:id=>1, :title=>"Your title", :location=>"Bermuda", :start=>"Sun, 05 Jan 2014 02:50:07 +0000", :end=>"Sun, 05 Jan 2014 02:51:46 +0000"}
```

The reason I have a separate **EventOccurence** model is to store recurring events separately, as was suggested in [this StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15842200/143895) post, as am I also trying to create a separate join table to store recurring events.

Currently, I am able to query *only* the Event objects fine for FullCalendar.  However, the Associations or **EventOccurrence** objects are not showing up using this:

```
@events = Event.all.includes(:event_occurrences)
```

Here is what I am currently attempting:

**calendar.js.erb**

```
....
eventSources: [{
        url: '/calendar/index'
    }],
....
```

**calendar_controller.erb**

```
def index
  @events = Event.all.includes(:event_occurrences)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @events }
  end
end
```

Am I going about this the right way? Does my **EventOccurrence** model need any additional fields to it?

**EDIT 1:**

Let me do my best to state what I am trying to achieve:

1. I have a calendar with Events.
2. Some of these Events are "recurring" events.
   => With these recurring events, I would like to store them separately into a 'join' table, so that they can be filtered within the parameters of a given month when queried.  (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15842200/143895)).

My models are above, as `Event` and `EventOccurrence`.  The way it currently works is:

1. If an event is *not* recurring, then it's basic event data is stored in the `Event` model (`:name, :start_time, :end_time`).
2. If an event *is* recurring, then it's basic information (`:name, :start_time, :end_time`) is stored in the `Event` model, and then, all of it's following occurrences are stored in the `EventOccurrence` model (`:event_id, :date`).  I omitted the (`:start_time` and `:end_time`) from the `EventOccurrence` model, because I assumed this would be handled by its parent in the `Event` model.

Is the best way to store and retrieve events based on the scenario I provided above?

Comment: What structure of a json output you need to get ? Is there an examples?

Comment: @itsnikolay, please see my edit in the question.

Comment: The issue is: you can not get `event_occurrences` in json? If it is then you could use `joins`  `@events = Event.joins(:event_occurrences)`

Comment: Hi @itsnikolay, so, what you did works.  BUT, it only works if the parent `Event` has an `EventOccurrence` object.  But, I also want to gather the `Event` objects that don't have an `EventOccurrence` as well.  I'm completely confused now.  I think it's an issue with my Models.  I will do my best to articulation what I am trying to achieve in an edit above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out what I need to do.  With some changes to my models, I came up with:

```
 --- !ruby/object:Event
   attributes:
   id: 
   name: 
   details: 
   location: 
   etc...
```

And

```
 --- !ruby/object:EventOccurrence
   attributes:
   id: 
   event_id:  
   start_time: 
   end_time:
```

And then, for the JSON that FullCalendar likes:

```
def index
@events = Event.all
@hash = []
@events.each do |e|
    @occurrences = e.event_occurrences
    @occurrences.each do |occurrence|
        @hash << {
          :id => e.id,
          :title => e.name,
          :location => e.location,
          :details => e.details,
          :start => occurrence.start_time.rfc822,
          :end => occurrence.end_time.rfc822,
        }
    end
end

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # index.html.erb
     format.json { render json: @hash }
   end
end
```

And this got all my events to display properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
def index
  @events = Event.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @events.to_json(include: :event_occurrences) }
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response (and patience), in trying to figure this out.  Based one what you gave me above, it basically only renders the `Event` objects and does not render any of the `EventOccurrences.`  So, I'm still perplexed as to what is actually happening.  Also, I did add one more piece of my `Event` model above where I define `as_json`, which I forgot to include.  Maybe this will help?  Thanks for sticking with me on this, as I am banging my head trying to figure it out!!

Comment: What if `@events = Event.includes(:event_occurrences)` other code stay the same, still no event_occurrences in json output ?

Comment: So let's  try to reproduce this issue on Github in a test project. If there's no better way.